# Insert to database from textbox using jquery.cleditor.css following by HTML tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, textarea

I am using cleditor to my app for create a interactive texarea. You can got it from this : [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)

The default of cleditor css like this :

```
    .cleditorMain {border:1px solid #ddd; padding:0 1px 1px; background-color:white}
    .cleditorMain iframe {border:none; margin:0; padding:0}
    .cleditorMain textarea {border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow-y:scroll; font:20pt Arial,Verdana; resize:both; outline:none /* webkit grip focus */}
    .cleditorToolbar {background: url('../img/toolbar.gif') repeat}
    .cleditorGroup {float:left; height:26px}
    .cleditorButton {float:left; width:24px; height:24px; margin:1px 0 1px 0; background: url('../img/buttons.gif')}
    .cleditorDisabled {opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=30)}
    .cleditorDivider {float:left; width:1px; height:23px; margin:1px 0 1px 0; background:#CCC}
    .cleditorPopup {border:solid 1px #999; background-color:white; position:absolute; font:10pt Arial,Verdana; cursor:default; z-index:10000}
    .cleditorList div {padding:2px 4px 2px 4px}
    .cleditorList p,
    .cleditorList h1,
    .cleditorList h2,
    .cleditorList h3,
    .cleditorList h4,
    .cleditorList h5,
    .cleditorList h6,
    .cleditorList font {padding:0; margin:0; background-color:Transparent}
    .cleditorColor {width:150px; padding:1px 0 0 1px}
    .cleditorColor div {float:left; width:14px; height:14px; margin:0 1px 1px 0}
    .cleditorPrompt {background-color:#F6F7F9; padding:4px; font-size:8.5pt}
    .cleditorPrompt input,
    .cleditorPrompt textarea {font:8.5pt Arial,Verdana;}
    .cleditorMsg {background-color:#FDFCEE; width:150px; padding:4px; font-size:8.5pt}
```

My question is 2 :

1. When I submit some text to database with submit button, html tag is still following the plain text ? How to remove it before submit ?
   Ex, I am type : "Hello "Enter" World ", Then, when submitting the text looked like this in mysql table "Hello "tag br" World
2. How can I change the wide of textarea, I try to change iframe and resize, still not working?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Isn't that the point of this? To have the tags shown in the text.... What would be the point of using this if you want to take all tags out of the text? Also you haven't told us how you are inserting this into a database, what language you are using, nothing. So we can't help you.

Comment: For the 2nd point, did you try inspect the element ?

Comment: Now, the 2nd point  is success. I just restart the browser after change some item in its css